# How to fix "Debug symbols for assembly nunit.framework could not be loaded correctly. Mono runtime doesn't support full pdb?"

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, nunit, rider

I installed Unity game engine and Rider IDE, after setting up everything. Then I created a new unity project and then that warning started popping. Everything is fresh installed and created. Every time I click on debug that warning shows up.

I tried searching in JetBrains forums, and here in StackOverflow some answers for this warning, I've tried many times with many keywords in Google but there are no answers

I also tried to download nunit framework from the official website and from nuget packages, also downloaded mono and configured in Rider, but the warning still there

I know it's something related to nunit and mono, but I don't exactly know what it is

Is it good? is it bad? how does it affect my projects? Can I remove the warning?

```
Debug symbols for assembly nunit.framework could not be loaded correctly. Mono runtime doesn't  support full pdb
```

Comment: what version of mono?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore it and vote this issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-12236